# django_auth_ldap, проблемы с разграничением доступа

Tags: python, django, ldap

Создал проект django и подключил к нему библиотеку django_auth_ldap, которая позволяет логиниться пользователям из IPA (причём членам только той группы, которую я вписал в настройках в файле settings.py). Всё работает.

Но есть задача - разграничить доступ к разным сайтам проекта, чтобы на один сайт могли логиниться пользователи из одной группы на IPA, а на другой сайт - из другой группы. Как это можно реализовать и возможно ли это вообще?